# Vanilla JS web component including <head> and <body>

Tags: javascript, web-component

Is it possible to include *head* and *body* as elements of a web component?

I tried the example below, but *web-html* is placed inside *body*, and *head* is empty:

**index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <web-html></web-html>
    <script type="module" src="html.js"></script>
</html>
```

**html.js**:

```
customElements.define('web-html', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        const template = document.createElement('template');
        template.innerHTML = `
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <title> Index </title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <slot> ... </slot>
            </body>
        `;
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
        shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    };
});
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @LuketheGeek I want to avoid repeating the head

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Custom Element must be included either in the `<head>` or in a `<body>` element. Therefore it should not contain any `<head>` or `<body>` element.

As a consequence, if you want to include content on both `<head>` and `<body>` you'll need do it  in a different way: with `document.head.appendChild()` for example.

Moreover, `<head>` and `<body>` must be direct children of `<html>` so you cannot include them in a custom element.

Answer (score 0):

Webcomponents are part of the body of a html document. When you like to include somphing in head, you musst do this via the dom api. But you can do the head stuff in a differend template and copy the content into the head tag.